# Proving non regularity of a language using Myhill-Nerode

Tags: computation-theory, dfa

Prove that the language defined over {0,1} where the number of 0s of x=number of 1s of x is not regular.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66433612/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136104/755 (see the original version on CS.SE).  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

Myhill-Nerode says that there are as many equivalence classes over the indistinguishability relation w.r.t. a regular language as there are states in a minimal DFA for that language.

Two strings w and x are indistinguishable w.r.t. a regular language L if for any y such that wy is in L, xy is also in L; and if for any z such that xz is in L, wz is in L also. In other words, w and x are indistinguishable if they can have exactly the same set of strings concatenated to them to get some string in L.

For your language, we can show the number of equivalence classes under this relation is infinite. Because no DFA has infinitely many states, this is a contradiction; by showing this we show the language is not regular.

In your case, we can show that 0^n is distinguishable from 0^m, for m > n, since the shortest string that can be appended to 0^n to get a string in your language is 1^n, whereas the shortest string that can be appended to 0^m to get a string in your language is 1^m, and m > n. Thus, each string 0^n is distinguishable from every other string 0^m, n != m, so there are infinitely many equivalence classes. As we said earlier, this means the language cannot be regular.

If we had found that a finite number of equivalence classes existed and named them, we'd have also found a minimal DFA for the language. Simply add one state per equivalence class and figure out the transitions.